# How to set different color for Alphabets in uilabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilabel, nsmutableattributedstring

I want to set gray color for alphabets in uilabel. how to set range value for that in NSMutableAttributedString.

Example :

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"1.2 Sun - 3.4 Mon"];
[attrString beginEditing];
[attrString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor grayColor] range: ]; // how to set range here for alphabets
[attrString endEditing];
```

Comment: do you need it dynamic or static?

Comment: dynamic... i have lots of other string instead of Sun, Mon... thousand number of other string,,.. but location of string is fixed in 2nd and 4th position with variable length of string...

Comment: You just wanted to make only alphabets as gray color right?.. Am trying to make it dynamic.

Comment: only alphabets as grey color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"1.2 Sun - 3.4 Mon"];

if([[attrString string] rangeOfString:@"Sun"].location != NSNotFound)
{
     NSRange range2 = [[attrString string] rangeOfString:@"Sun"];

    [attrString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor grayColor] range:range2];
}

if([[attrString string] rangeOfString:@"Mon"].location != NSNotFound)
{
    NSRange range2 = [[attrString string] rangeOfString:@"Mon"];

    [attrString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor grayColor] range:range2];
}
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: This works for static.. you need to hard code "Sun" and "Mon".